# comparing a date value in one table against multiple values in another to categorise by age

Tags: mysql, case

I have created a form which allows users to enter multiple, unlimited month number values and label them to use against inventory to categorise the age of each item.

**Table 1 - AgeConfig -  Manually enterted by users**

| id | customer_id | start_month | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 171 | 0 | Current |
| 2 | 171 | 3 | 3-6 Months |
| 3 | 171 | 6 | 6-12 Months |
| 4 | 171 | 12 | 12+ Months |

**Table 2 - Inventory**

| id | customer_id | item_no | entry_date | qty | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 171 | CH72394 | 2022-01-28 | 3 | 430.10 |
| 1 | 171 | CH72395 | 2022-02-28 | 4 | 30.10 |
| 1 | 171 | CH72396 | 2022-03-28 | 1 | 130.10 |
| 1 | 171 | CH72397 | 2022-01-22 | 5 | 320.50 |
| 1 | 171 | CH72398 | 2022-02-22 | 1 | 22.30 |
| 1 | 171 | CH72399 | 2022-01-22 | 1 | 92.30 |
| 1 | 171 | CH72400 | 2022-01-24 | 1 | 392.80 |

I am trying to present this in SQL using CASE but I dont know how to compare it against a variable number of rows and make sure I start at the highest and work to the lowest.

I am trying to use CASE but am stumped

```sql
SELECT  customer_id,
    item_no,
    entry_date,
    CASE
        WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, entry_date, NOW()) > MAX(start_month)) THEN `label`
        WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, entry_date, NOW()) > 2NDMAX(start_month)) THEN `label`
        WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, entry_date, NOW()) > 3RDMAX(start_month)) THEN `label`
        ...
    END,
    qty,
    cost
FROM Inventory
INNER JOIN AgeConfig USING (customer_id)
WHERE customer_id = 171
```

I dont know how to incrementally test against highest down to lowest and then use the corresponding label so that the result is:

| id | customer_id | item_no | entry_date | age | qty | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 171 | CH72394 | 2022-01-28 | 3-6 Months | 3 | 430.10 |
| 1 | 171 | CH72395 | 2022-02-28 | Current | 4 | 30.10 |
| 1 | 171 | CH72396 | 2021-03-28 | Current | 1 | 130.10 |
| 1 | 171 | CH72397 | 2022-01-22 | 3-6 Months | 5 | 320.50 |
| 1 | 171 | CH72398 | 2021-08-22 | 6-12 Months | 1 | 22.30 |
| 1 | 171 | CH72399 | 2021-01-22 | 12+ Months | 4 | 92.30 |
| 1 | 171 | CH72400 | 2022-01-24 | 3-6 Months | 1 | 392.80 |

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using php in between to get a fast resolution - probably not the most efficient but it works. Still interested to know if there is an SQL only solution

`SELECT period_start_mth, period_label FROM AgeConfig WHERE customer_id = 171 ORDER BY period_start_mth DESC`

Then built the SQL with the resulting array

```
$entry_date_query = "";

if ( !empty($agePeriods) )
{           
    foreach ( $agePeriods as $period )
    {
        $entry_date_query .= "WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, entry_date, NOW()) >= {$period["period_start_mth"]}) THEN '{$period["period_label"]}'".PHP_EOL;
    }
    
    $entry_date_query = "CASE" . PHP_EOL . $entry_date_query . "ELSE 'Other'" . PHP_EOL . "END AS entry_date_age,";
}
else
{
    $entry_date_query = "'Default Catch All' as entry_date_age,";
}

$query = "SELECT  customer_id,
    item_no,
    entry_date,
    $entry_date_query
    qty,
    cost
FROM Inventory
WHERE customer_id = 171";
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH 
cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           COALESCE(LEAD(start_month) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY start_month), 10000) - 1 finish_month
    FROM AgeConfig
)
SELECT *
FROM Inventory
JOIN cte USING (customer_id)
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, entry_date, CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN start_month AND finish_month
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78b28b19df1260ef6ce0a76aac3cfcd0